# Visual Studio C++ get "cl.exe" MSB6006 error: exit code 2

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

I have one large **vector** in one header file **myVector.h**

> Vector size aprox. 1M

```
std::vector<byte> xSh = {
0x11,0xFF,0xA1,0x36,0x06,0xC3,0xB5,0x16,0x03,0x01,0x5B,0x6C,0x5E,0x36,0x26,
0x6C,0x7F,0x4E,0x8D,0xC8,0x13,0xB4,0xF6,0x74,0x01,0x5B,0x6C,0x5E,0x36,0x26,
...
}
```

When i include this **myVector.h** file in my code, my compiller get this error

> 1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\VC\VCTargets\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(423,5): error MSB6006: "CL.exe" exited with code 2.

[Screenshot of Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(423,5)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/86AXa.png)

When i shorten my array, works fine. I think my CL.exe or Visual Studio has limits. 
I also change my C++ compiller /Zm paramter but not helps.

Also i try to copy my vector to my code but not solved my problem. Its not connected with header file. I think this is limitation.

Comment: _Never_ allocate variables in header files and all your problems will go away.

Comment: Unfortunately I tried this, copied everything to my code. but the error did not pass.

Comment: workaround could be to create 2 smallest vectors, then add them together, avoiding the too big array.

Comment: Have you tried with a regular array?

Comment: @molbdnilo array works fine. but i have small problem with array, i thnk must be way to increase this limitation. Array is my last option.

Comment: @AaronYordanyan please provide a [MCVE], but, yes, variables in header files is almost always wrong.